# Deeper Learning in Physiology?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, book-recommendation

I am a Pharmacology and Toxicology major at a large state school. I was only required to take physics I and II. (algebra based)

At first I thought that was fine, but I soon began to realize that I can't just memorize like my professor and book asks me too, but I need to go in-depth.

So my question is this, I am looking for a way to learn the "physics and chemistry behind physiology" or deeper that what we are taught?

For example, say we are taught that atherosclerosis can cause aneurysms and that aneurysms can rupture.

But what we aren't taught is that blood flow through a closed vessel is constant, so any dilatation in the mid-length will increase the cross-sectional area and decrease the fluid velocity to maintain flow.

In accordance with Bernoulli's principle, the decrease in velocity is met with an increase in pressure, which increases wall tension. Vessel integrity is already compromised from the three layer degradation. So now you start to see this great positive feedback loop whereby atherosclerosis damages the vessel wall causing it to dilate, which increases the pressure, which causes it to dilate further, which damages the vessel wall further, etc, etc, until the aneurysm finally ruptures. (I did not write this example, but it is an example of how I would like to learn it.  I would like to know how the author of that explanation came to that conclusion or what kind of book would explain in heavy detail.)

The question I am asking how can I learn the "science" behind the physiology?  I'm a type of learner that needs to know the how and why.  Will I need to take more physics classes?

** Sorry if I posted in the wrong section, I am new to stack exchange!

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy, use google + pathophysiology and read some articles in the actual topic. There are a lot of [pathophysiology books](http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Books-Pathophysiology/zgbs/books/227602) as well (some of them pretty expensive). Another way to do [an online course](https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=physiology).

Just a simple search about your example:

> It is known that AAAs are characterized by destruction of elastin and
>   collagen in the media and adventitia, loss of medial smooth muscle
>   cells with thinning of the vessel wall, and transmural infiltration of
>   lymphocytes and macrophages. Atherosclerosis is a common underlying
>   feature of aneurysms. However, atherosclerosis is not the primary
>   driving factor in the development of AAAs. Atherosclerosis is a
>   disease that is widespread throughout the vasculature, however
>   aneurysms only form in specific locations and only in certain
>   individuals. Additionally, atherosclerosis is primarily a disease of
>   the intima, while aneurysm formation primarily affects the media and
>   adventitia.

- 2009 - [The Pathogenesis of Abdominal Aortic Aneurysms](http://www.vascularweb.org/research/Pages/the-pathogenesis-of-abdominal-aortic-aneurysms.aspx)